# Calling REST API with bearer token and fetch url

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in javascript
I'm here to learn there can be mistakes in my code.

I made a rest api in express.js that distributes pokemons for example.
It works perfectly and it is online.
I made all the tests of different accesses GET/POST,  AUTH/TOKEN with postman with success.

step 1:
to access this API
I connect successfully from my page "index.html" which calls a .js file in which I "fetch" the url : https://myDomain/api/login with a "bearer token
step 2 :

From "index.html" I can access my list of objects with the div : "#content".

step 3:
From this list, I want to be able to click on one of the elements to display this object in detail to the div : "#output"
for the moment I have created an input in which I fill in the "id" as "value" of the object and when I click on it I display it with the "fetchList" function
it works.
If I try to create this input from my "for loop" (it is my target) I get a token refusal.
I do not understand why it works outside the "for loop" and not inside
can you guide me ?

I am really blocked
thanks in advance

my js :

```
// Create html container
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.setAttribute('class', 'container');
output.appendChild(container);

// Create html Card element
const card = document.createElement('div');
card.setAttribute('class', 'card-single');
container.appendChild(card);

// Create html object header
const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.setAttribute('class', 'header');
h1.setAttribute('id', 'header');

// Create  date
const createdAt = document.createElement('p');
createdAt.setAttribute('class', 'date');

//==================================≠≠≠≠≠====================≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠
// Step 1 : "Get JWT token
//==================================≠≠≠≠≠====================≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠
fetch("https://myDomain/api/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ username: "username", password: "password" }),
  headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" }
})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res.token;
    })
    .then((token) => {
      fetchlist(token)
      $('.clickMe').click(function(){
        // alert(this.id);
        fetchSingle(token)
      });
    });

//==================================≠≠≠≠≠====================≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠
// Step 2 : "Get Object list
//==================================≠≠≠≠≠====================≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠
const fetchlist = (token) => {
  const baseUrl = "https://myDomain/api/pokemons/"
  try {
    fetch(baseUrl, {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
    })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status == 200) {
            // alert ("json ok");
            // console.log(response);
            return response.json();
          } else {
            throw new Error("NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR");
          }
        })
        .then((poke) => {
          displayList(poke);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }

  const contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.setAttribute('class', 'container');
  contentDiv.appendChild(container);

  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',

// BELOW IS MY INPUT OUTSIDE FOR LOOP [WORKING FINE!]
      `
 <!--        <input type="text" onclick="fetchSingle();" class="clickMe" placeholder="id?">-->
      `
  )

  function displayList(poke) {
    for (let i in poke.data) {
      let z = poke.data[i];
      // console.log("Z :" + z);

      // Create html for Card element
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
      container.appendChild(card);

      card.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',

// BELOW IS MY INPUT INSIDE FOR LOOP [NOT WORKING]
          `
           <input type="text" value="${z.id}" onclick="fetchSingle();" class="clickMe">
          `
      )
      // Create html for object name
      const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.setAttribute('class', 'header');
      // h1.textContent = z.name;
      h1.innerHTML = z.name;
      card.appendChild(h1);
    }
  }
}

//==================================≠≠≠≠≠====================≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠
// Step 3 : "Get  Single Object
//==================================≠≠≠≠≠====================≠≠≠≠≠≠≠≠
const fetchSingle = (token) => {
  const myid = event.srcElement.value;
  console.log("Myid : " + myid );

  try {
    fetch("https://myDomain/api/pokemons/" + myid, {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
    })
        // alert(token)
        // alert(myid)
        .then((singleresponse) => {
          if (singleresponse.status == 200) {
            //   alert ("json ok");
            // console.log(singleresponse.json());
            return singleresponse.json();
          } else {
            throw new Error("NETWORK RESPONSE ERROR");
          }
        })

        .then((single) => {
          if (!myid) {
            console.log("data null");
            // alert("data null");
          } else {
            // alert("data ok")
            displaySingle(single);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }

  function displaySingle(single) {

    const poke = single.data;

    // update name
    h1.textContent = poke.name;
    card.appendChild(h1);


    // single object update  date
    const event = new Date(poke.created);
    createdAt.textContent = "Created at : " + event.toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'UTC'});
    card.appendChild(createdAt);

  }
}
```

My html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Fetch & display API data using JavaScript</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>
<body>
<main>
  <h1>Single result view </h1>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <h1>List view</h1>
  <div id="content"></div>

</main>
  <script src="file.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Json data

```
{
    "message": "La liste des pokémons a bien été récupérée.",
    "data": [
        {
            "types": [
                "Poison"
            ],
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Abo",
            "hp": 16,
            "cp": 4,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/023.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Insecte",
                "Poison"
            ],
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Aspicot",
            "hp": 16,
            "cp": 2,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/013.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Plante",
                "Poison"
            ],
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bulbizarre",
            "hp": 25,
            "cp": 5,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/001.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Eau"
            ],
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Carapuce",
            "hp": 21,
            "cp": 4,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/007.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Feu"
            ],
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Groupix",
            "hp": 17,
            "cp": 8,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/037.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Fée"
            ],
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Mélofée",
            "hp": 25,
            "cp": 5,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/035.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Normal",
                "Vol"
            ],
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Piafabec",
            "hp": 14,
            "cp": 5,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/021.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Electrik"
            ],
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Pikachu",
            "hp": 21,
            "cp": 7,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/025.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Normal"
            ],
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Rattata",
            "hp": 18,
            "cp": 6,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/019.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Normal",
                "Vol"
            ],
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Roucool",
            "hp": 30,
            "cp": 7,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/016.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Normal"
            ],
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Sabelette",
            "hp": 19,
            "cp": 3,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/027.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        },
        {
            "types": [
                "Feu"
            ],
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Salamèche",
            "hp": 28,
            "cp": 6,
            "picture": "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/004.png",
            "created": "2022-07-15T12:41:44.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: in :
 `
const fetchSingle = (token) => {
`

if I fill the token in hard in the js like this :

`fetch("https://example.com/api/pokemons/"+ myid, {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${"exampleTokenHardCoded"}`}
    })
`
and not :
`    fetch("https://example.com/api/pokemons/"+ myid, {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
    })
`
it work fine
I don't understand why the token is transmitted in outside for loop
and not in the other outside for loop
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare two variables in your javascript file. Which at least brings the code you posted to error.

In the `displayList` function the variables `i` and `z` are never declared. This probably causes your error.
Change it like this:

```
for (let i in poke.data) {
  let z = poke.data[i];
```

Like this, it works for me. Not sure if there are more problems with your code.

I recommend you change your service's username and password after posting it on StackOverflow

Comment: @Laluka _"You forgot to declare two variables in your javascript file. This leads to at least one error in the code you posted."_
**which variables are they?**

_ "In the displayList function the variables i and z are never declared. This is probably the cause of your error. "_
**I added the let but no change**

Comment: did you try ?
 commented :
`// BELOW IS MY INPUT OUTSIDE FOR LOOP
      `
 <!--        <input type="text" onclick="fetchSingle();" class="clickMe" placeholder="id?">-->
`
and 
uncommented :
`
// BELOW IS MY INPUT INSIDE FOR LOOP
          `
           <input type="text" value="${z.id}" onclick="fetchSingle();" class="clickMe">
`